# How can I implement automatic backups in less than an hour on Atlas MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I need backups for restoring the state of MongoDB in less than an hour, 15 minutes for example. 
I am using Atlas on which I can see backup features in minimum 1 hour.

[image: Atlas backups]

From previous image you could suppose that the minimum allowed is 1 hour. However, on the website they say that they use Oplog with operations of at least 1 minute.

[image: Point in time recovery]

I know that a possible solution could be have `crons` that create backups and upload them to something like S3.

But using atlas, can I have backups with restore feature every 15 minutes? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good explanation of point-in-time restores  [here](https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/01/25/mongodb-point-in-time-restore/).

The backup snapshots (what you are referring to in the screenshots) must *predate* in time the restore point. To restore to a point newer than the snapshot time, oplog is replayed from the *live deployment*.

This is also alluded to [in the official documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/backup/cloud-backup/overview/#continuous-cloud-backups).

So, to restore to a specific point in time, my understanding is you should be looking at the *restore* UI somewhere, not at UI that configures backup snapshots.